# Change navbar button active status on scrolling from one div to the next

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small HTML page with a navbar and 2 jumbotrons

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Play Home</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" id="HomeButton">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Campus" id="CampusButton">Campus</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" id="Home">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <!--Content here-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="Campus">
    <div class="jumbotron">
     <!--Content Here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get to change the navbar nav active from one to the other on scrolling on the page using JQuery?

I have tried this -

```
$("#Home").scroll(function() {
    console.log("Here");
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $("#HomeButton").parent().addClass("active");
});

$("#Campus").scroll(function() {
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $("#CampusButton").parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're actually after scrollspy.

add this to your body tag.

`<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">`

and it should work, one thing to note is that the href of the navbar's `<a>` tags must be the same as the `<div>`'s id.

Also, you should probably use all lowercase in your `id`'s, I think it's good convention. :)

check this link out if you're after any additional info.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy